# GNUMake: How to separate the make file statements after any rule?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

**Case 1**

```
all:
   <TAB> @echo hei

#done
ifneq ($(DD),1)
   <TAB> TESTVAR:=1
endif
```

**Case 2**

```
all:
   <TAB> @echo hei

#done
ifneq ($(DD),1)
   <SPACE> TESTVAR:=1
endif
```

**Case 3**

```
ifneq ($(DD),1)
   <TAB> TESTVAR:=1
endif

all:
   <TAB> @echo hei
```

As you all know case #2 and #3 will work, but not case #1.

Below is error for case #1,

```
hei
TESTVAR:=1
/bin/sh: TESTVAR:=1: command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

Reason is **TESTVAR:=1** is interpreted as command instead of makefile variable, because the statment comes after a rule.

**My question here is, how to avoid this problem without using any fixes like case #2 & case #3 ?**

Comment: Easy. Don't indent non-shell commands with a tab! I use two spaces for intenting, and set my editor tabs to 10 spaces or above.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a tab in front of a Makefile assignment.  Take it out (or replace it with spaces) and you should be fine.

Comment: But <TAB> is usable until first rule commences. See my case #3 example.

Comment: As a crude workaround, put an assignment in front of the `ifneq` without any indentation.  Then you can have indentation on the assignment inside the `ifneq`.  (I still don't think this is a good idea, or worth your effort, but there you have it.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "fix" this.  Many people don't realize this, but a "recipe context" does not stop at a blank line, or a comment, and certainly not at a conditional statement like `ifdef`.

When make is parsing a recipe for a rule, it will consider all subsequent lines that begin with TAB to be part of the recipe, until it finds a line which does *not* begin with a TAB.  Blank lines (including lines containing nothing but comments) and conditional lines do not end the recipe.

The only thing that will terminate a recipe is another rule or a variable assignment, that does not start with a TAB.  Or the end of the file, of course.